# How to get the status of the Scenario ran in behave

Tags: python-behave

Can some one please tell me, how can I get the status of the scenario which ran with `behave` in python?

I want to get the status (success or error) of the test cases ran in `after_scenario` method.

Answer (score 3):

As of Behave 1.2.6 status is an enumeration, so:

```
# -file- environment.py
from behave.model_core import Status

def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    print(Scenario.status)

    if scenario.status == Status.failed:
        print('more details:...')
```

The `import` is only needed for comparing the status with `Status.failed`, e.g. to print some more details.

The `status` is a read-only summary of the scenario’s run:

> - Status.untested: the scenario has not been completely tested yet.
> - Status.skipped: one or more steps of this scenario was passed over during testing.
> - Status.passed: the scenario was tested successfully.
> - Status.failed: one or more steps of this scenario failed.
>
> Changed in version 1.2.6: Use Status enum class (was: string)

See: http://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#behave.model.Scenario.status

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy to do with behave. The `Scenario` class has an attribute called `status`. You can use this in the `after_scenario` method like so:

```
# -file- environment.py

def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    print (scenario.status)
```

This should return one of:

- `untested`:
  The scenario was has not been completely tested yet.
- `skipped`:
  One or more steps of this scenario was passed over during testing.
- `passed`: The scenario was tested successfully.
- `failed`:
  One or more steps of this scenario failed.